# Access webcam in silverlight returning false

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I've done a Silverlight application that access my web cam.

**Code:**

```
public MainPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();      

  if (CaptureDeviceConfiguration.AllowedDeviceAccess || CaptureDeviceConfiguration.RequestDeviceAccess())
  {
      snapshot.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
      src.Start();
  }
  // Event Wiring
  //cameraButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(cameraButton_Click);
  photoButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(photoButton_Click);
  saveButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(saveButton_Click);

  // Setup Capture Source
  cameraBrush.SetSource(src);
}
```

**Problem:**

The function below always return false. I try to run in debug mode and in release mode, but without success.

```
if (CaptureDeviceConfiguration.AllowedDeviceAccess || CaptureDeviceConfiguration.RequestDeviceAccess())
  {
      snapshot.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
      src.Start();
  }
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be in Release mode its must. No debugger attached.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9258569/413032

What CaptureDeviceConfiguration.GetAvailableVideoCaptureDevices(); returns?

Comment: `CaptureDeviceConfiguration.GetAvailableVideoCaptureDevices();` return 1 in debug mode. I've opened a new solution in Visual Studio and put just the Silverlight app. Works fine. But when I put the Silverlight app with my Web App, doesn't work even in release mode.

Comment: In your Web project setting=>Web section, check Silverlight Debugging is checked. Also where we change debug and release there is a Configuration Manager option.Please check if in your Configuration Manager Debug mode options are all Debug for all of your projects.

Comment: I think I made a mistake. I put the `CaptureDeviceConfiguration.RequestDeviceAccess()` in the `MainPage()`, and I read that it has to be done in a Click event, for example.